# Django model field validation without a custom form

Tags: django, django-models

I am using a django DateField in my model.

```
class CalWeek(models.Model):
  start_monday = models.DateField(verbose_name="Start monday")
```

I have a custom validation method that is specific to my modelField: I want to make sure that it is actually a Monday. I currently have no reason to use a custom ModelForm in the admin--the one Django generates is just fine. Creating a custom form class just so i can utilize the `clean_start_monday(self)`[1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) sugar that django Form classes provide seems like a lot of work just to add some field validation.  I realize I can [override the model's clean method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) and raise a `ValidationError` there.  However, this is not ideal: these errors get attributed as non-field errors and end up at the top of the page, not next to the problematic user input--not an ideal UX.

Is there an easy way to validate a specific model field and have your error message show up next to the field in the admin, without having to use a custom form class?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can look into Django Validators.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/

You would put the validator before the class, then set the validator in the Field.

```
def validate_monday(date):
    if date.weekday() != 0:
        raise ValidationError("Please select a Monday.")

class CalWeek(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(validators=[validate_monday])
```

Comment: Nice! I don't know how i'd overlooked this.

Comment: Cool! Hadn't used one before, but this is.. very clean. Post clean validators!