# BooleanField custom validator not working

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models

I wrote a custom validator for a `BooleanField` to ensure saving an object with a `true` value. I took the idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12127947/1331671).

Here's my model:

```
terms_accepted = models.BooleanField(u"Terms accepted", validators=[validate_boolean])
```

Here's the custom validator:

```
def validate_boolean(value):
if not value:
    raise ValidationError(u"Durp!")
```

But the validator is never executed. I put a debug breakpoint there but nothing happens.

I used non-custom validators before (on IntegerFields) and they work like a charm, for example:

```
validators=[MinValueValidator(1900), MaxValueValidator(2014)]
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Or is it maybe a `django` bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)  Docs for validating objects:

You can `clean_fields(exclude=None)` which will validate all fields in model except the fields in `exclude`.

From [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run) doc:

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a
>   model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators
>   on any fields that are included in your form.

More information about validating [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).

**EDIT**

For field specific errors, `clean_<field>()` can be used in `forms`. Example:

```
terms_accepted= forms.BooleanField()
-------
-------
def clean_terms_accepted(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    if data['terms_accepted'] is not None:
        return True
    else:
        msg="Durp!"
        self._errors["terms_accepted"] = self.error_class([msg])
        return False
```

Comment: well, thanks. basically what I need but it doesn't return a field-specific error. That would be my solution... any idea if this is possible?

Comment: You can use `clean()` in forms. I have added an example in answer, so please check it.

Comment: Ok, now I found it - I went for the validate_<field_name> solution from RESTframework: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#validation